# Using CMake with ifort compiler

Tags: cmake, fortran, intel-fortran

I am using CMake 2.8.7 on a Linux machine with Intel 11.0 compilers. I am trying to use CMake for the first time as I would like to build this project on both Windows and Linux machines.

I though of using a simple approach first and used a standard Hello World example:
My src/HelloWorld.f90:

```
!Test helloworld in Fortran using Cmake
program hello
    print *, "Hello World!"
end program hello
```

My main CMakeLists.txt:

```
# States that CMake required version must be greater than 2.8.7
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7)
enable_language (Fortran)
project(helloworld Fortran)
add_subdirectory(src)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(helloworld PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE FORTRAN)
```

My src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7)

# Include the directory itself as a path to include directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

# For a large number of source files you can create it in a simpler way
# using file() function:
file(GLOB helloworld_SOURCES *.f90)
```

I still get an error which says CMAKE_FORTRAN_LINK_EXECUTABLE variable missing. I looked at [Abinader's CMake tutorial#1](http://www.abinader.com.br/bruno/how-cmake-simplifies-the-build-process-part-1-basic-build-system/), but haven't had success so far.

any suggestions?? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hi! Did you find an answer for that? I have some issues with ifort, too, but with a different context: Windows. ;-) It seems, that CMake's support for Intel's Fortran compiler is not so good... :-(

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, as I've never used fortran with cmake, but I can see a few issues here.

First of all: where is your target `helloworld` defined? `project` is not a target.

Secondly: where do you use `helloworld_SOURCES` variable?

Try a more regular way. In your src/CMakeLists.txt add line at the end of file with:

```
add_executable(helloworld ${helloworld_SOURCES})
```

Also remove `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(helloworld PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE FORTRAN)` from main one as it should not be necessary.

Last advice: try not to use `file(GLOB )`. It is better to define list of all files manualy.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the upper-case "FORTRAN", when setting the linker language is the problem. Try writing it as "Fortran" as in the enable_language statement. CMake derives the variables it uses from the language and this causes CMake to look for CMAKE_FORTRAN_LINK_EXECUTABLE instead of CMAKE_Fortran_LINK_EXECUTABLE.

Comment: I used CMAKE_Fortran_LINK_EXECUTABLE, but CMake still complains. Is there some flag that needs to be specified for Fortran??

Answer (score 0):

As also mentioned by Michal, the `add_executable` has to be added to your CMakeLists.txt.

I tested your issue with the following CMake configurations files

main CMakeLists.txt:

```
# States that CMake required version must be greater than 2.8.7
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7)
enable_language (Fortran)
project(helloworld Fortran)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7)

add_executable(helloworld HelloWorld.f90)
```

under Linux for following versions:

> ifort (IFORT) 16.0.0.20150815
>
> cmake version 2.8.12.2

I prefer to use `cmake-gui`. There you can define the `ifort` compiler as follows:

After definition of source code and binary folder, e.g. `build`, press "Configure" and select

[image: cmake-gui_01]

Click "Next" and define the following compilers

[image: cmake-gui_02]

Click "Finish" and "Generate".

Go to `build/src` folder and execute `make`. The `helloworld` executable is generated with `ifort` successfully and could be called here.

Hint: If `ifort` is already the default native compiler on your Linux computer then you don't have to specify it in `cmake-gui` and can go ahead with the first option "Use default native compilers".

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this step-by-step:

1) Your Fortran Hello, world is OK!

#### src/hello.f90

```
!Test helloworld in Fortran using Cmake
program hello
     print *, "Hello World!"
end program hello
```

2) Now let's write the "inner" CMakeLists.txt

#### src/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(helloworld hello.f90)
set_target_properties(
    helloworld 

    PROPERTIES 
    LINKER_LANGUAGE Fortran
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build)
```

Here we've created an `executable` file, which you haven't in your question. Also, we've set its linker language to `Fortran` (it's case-sensitive parameter!) and the output directory for the compiled file.

3) Now we'll create the "main" CMakeLists.txt

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
# States that CMake required version must be greater than 2.8.7
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7)

project(helloworld Fortran)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

Here we've specified the `src` subdirectory with inner CMakeLists.txt and the compiler language - it's enough to use `project()` function, there's not need to use it together with `enable_language()`.

4) Finally, let's build our code in out-of-source manner and run it!

1. `cmake -S . -B build`
2. `cmake --build build`
3. `./build/helloworld`